# Procedural generation of HTML through simple functions.. In PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, function, materialize

I have a few functions that make HTML easier to output through PHP.

```
function div($id = '', $class = '', $content = '', $attr = ''){
    $div = '<div';
    $div.= ($id=='') ? '' : ' id="'.$id.'"';
    $div.= ($class=='') ? '' : ' class="'.$class.'"';
    $div.= ($attr=='') ? '' : ' '.$attr;
    return $div.'>'.$content.'</div>;
}
```

To me, functions like this seem to make web development easier because they allow me to focus on generating the CONTENT of the website rather than the HTML of the website. I use this function in other functions (row(),col(),chart()) that make it much easier to output HTML that will look great in websites that have Materialize or Bootstrap grid systems loaded.

Now, I understand that a larger website will use a function like this many, many times. Potentially creating overhead.

Eh screw it. Do you use anything like this to make it easier to generate HTML for your websites? Or am I crazy for thinking that

```
echo '<div class="row"><div class="col m6"><div class="card">'.$content.'</div></div></div>';
```

Is a pain in the ass to type every time something needs to be shown nicely with the added effect of being responsive?

Just looking for some opinions I guess. I've searched around and haven't found anything satisfying I suppose. This is my first question on here.

Thanks

Comment: A larger website would never use a function like that.  Large sites and systems are built on frameworks which separate the presentation from the logic.  Check out frameworks like Symfony, Laravel, Yii, Zend.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ryancramerdesign/regular/blob/master/site-regular/templates/_uikit.php

Answer (score 0):

I used to do something very similar. My navbar templates for instance would be in a function called nav() and I would just output the return at the top of each page. However, now there are many great "templating engines" which do this for you and have a very clean syntax that allows you to modularize your whole front end.

My favorite is [Blade](https://packagist.org/packages/philo/laravel-blade).

It is pre-built into the Laravel PHP framework if you are interested but it is also available as a standalone.

```
    //extends will essentially derive your basic layout(nav and such) from a template of yours
    @extends('layouts.main')
    //a section tag will match put the inside code in the matching tag on your main layout
    @section('content')
        //blade's if statement syntax
        @if(true)
            //blade's foreach loop syntax
            @foreach($variables as $v)
                //the shorthand notation for php echo is double braces
                {{ $php_variable }}
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endsection
```